# Purging cached urls in akamai through java code using Fast Purge Open API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, akamai, purge

has any one tried to purge content using Open Api Purge V3 using java. As i am not able to understand the process by their documents provided on Akamai portal.I referred this below link to proceed but no luck till now
https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/article/OPEN-API-Fast-Purge-and-Java?language=en_US

Also another question, is their any possibility to purge by directory instead of purge by URL in Fast Purge API via java code using open API.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot purge by directory using APIs. You will have use something called as ECCU to purge directories. I would assign a CPCODE for the directory of interest to be purged and then use CPCODE to purge.

Regarding Java code, i would suggest you to copy and paste the code into a file and trace it. Ideally following are the steps.

1. Read the credentials (usually from .edgerc file)
2. Establish a session to Akamai API server
3. Build the POST object containing URLs and CPCODE.
4. Issue a POST request, and expect a 201 response.